# How to store Map View Annotation values in NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

I am trying to obtain annotation property like title and store it in a dictionary.I can see the value in NSLog but not able to store in a dictionary.What am I missing?

```
 - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
 {
      NSString *str = view.annotation.title;
      NSLog(@"%@", str);                // shows name 
     [dict setValue:str forKey:@"name"]; // shows 0 key/value pairs and app crashes
     NSLog(@"dict output :-%@", dict);    // shows null
```

Comment: did you initialise the dictionary ?

Comment: dictionary is instance of `NSMutableDictionary`?

Comment: Then you should get a different error, right? I think it must be null. If you attempt to set a value on a mutable, you should get an error that there is no such selector.

Comment: `- (void)setValue:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key` instance method of  `NSMutableDictionary`, not `NSDictionary`. You can not add new object to instance of `NSDictionary`.

Comment: I thought setObject is for NSMutable Dictionary and setValue is for NSDictionary

Comment: No, both methods (`setObject` and `setValue`) instance methods of `NSMutableDictionary` https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Seriously, Dude, you are already on this site, use it:

[How to addObject of NSMutableDictionary to NSMutableArray in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957883/how-to-addobject-of-nsmutabledictionary-to-nsmutablearray-in-a-loop)

And use logging, will make your life much easier. If you are using Xcode 5, put this all into a unit test. They run in sub second times.